# TPT load operator to load relational tables to Teradata target

Tags: teradata

Can we use TPT load operator to load Oracle relational tables to Teradata target?

Since FLOAD only loads from flat files, can we use Tables here in TPT LOAD operators?

What can be the workaround this? We have the oracle tables which needs to be loaded to teradata target using TPT LOADER CONNECTIONS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The high level functionality of TPT is such that any Producer operator can be used with any Consumer operator.

Load Operator is a consumer, it can be used with any producer operator. Some common options when loading from Oracle are

1. Data Connector Producer
2. ODBC Connector

In first option, you can extract data from Oracle and dump (spool) it on the disk, then use Data Connector Producer to create a script somewhat similar in functionality as the traditional Fastload utility.

Or the second option; you can use the ODBC connector to use an ODBC connection to extract data directly from Oracle and send to the Load operator for loading to Teradata.

I think the second option is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Xenodevil,
I guess thats what i was looking for. I will have to implement and see.

Comment: Bear in mind that ODBC has its own overheads and isn't recommended for extracting high amounts of data.
ODBC will mostly choke one network or other involved between Oracle and TD nodes or maybe on the Oracle server itself based upon its performance constraints.
Also, generating metadata is a pain when using ODBC.